# Print line from target in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

The first block is the input file that is used in this program (simply just a .txt file). 
In the 'SearchByTitle' function, it is correctly picking up on if the target is in the list, as well as printing it out successfully, however, it will only print out the actual target word. Is there a way to get it to print out the entire line? For example, if 'Sempiternal' was searched, could it return Sempiternal, Bring Me The Horizon, Metalcore, 14.50, rather than just the target word?
Also, when SortingByPrice, it will only return the closest price less than the target, rather than all that are less.

Any nudge in the right direction would be great, i've been messing with this for days.

INPUT FILE:

```
Sempiternal,Bring Me The Horizon,Metalcore,14.50
Badlands,Halsey,Indie Pop,19.95
Wildlife,La Dispute,Post Hardcore,9.60
Move Along,The All American Rejects,Punk Rock,10.20
```

FUNCTIONS:

```
def createDatabase(CD):
    aList = []
    file = open(CD) 
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip().split(",")    #strip \n and split at ,
        aList.append(line)      #add lines into formerly empty aList
    for i in range(len(aList)):
        aList[i][3] = float(aList[i][3])    #override line for price to be float
    return aList


def PrintList(aList):
    for line in aList:
        album = str(line[0])   
        artist = str(line[1])
        genre = str(line[2])
        price = str(line[3])
        print("Album: " + album + " Artist: " + artist + " Genre: " + genre + " Price: $" + price)
    return    


def FindByTitle(aList):
    target = input("Enter Title to Search: ")
    title = [item[0] for item in aList]
    for item in title:
        if target in item:
            print("Title name found in database: " + target)
            return aList
        print("Title not found")
        return None


def FindByPrice(aList):
    target = float(input("Enter Maximum Price: "))
    price = [item[3] for item in aList]
    for item in price:
        if item <= target:
            print(item)
            return aList
    print("Artist not found")
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the package Pandas for that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_input_file)

df[df[0]=='Sempiternal']
```

The idea of pandas is to store your file in a dataframe, then the operations upon your file are far easier than with loops (and more efficient).
Just remember that the dataframe will be stored into your RAM, so take care with huge input files.

Comment: how does that account for if a different title is searched for though?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. If you want to print a list a rows corresponding to a list of titles you can use isin() like this: df[df[0].isin(list_of_tunes)]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following,

```
def find_by_title(rows):
    query = input('Title: ')
    found = [row for row in rows if row[0] == query]
    return found[0] if found else None
```

If it is a big list and you want to break out once you found it, then

```
for row in rows:
    if row[0] == query:
        found = row
        break
```

All your functions can be cleaned up to some extent. **Please don't use `camelCase` for function and variable names, use `snake_case`**. The former is very off-putting.